# how to get array kets on selecting value from react search auto select

Tags: jquery, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have an array shown below

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "Success",
  "VisArr": [
    {
      "VKey": "john Doe 0101 jd@example.com",
      "VisName": "john doe",
      "VisOrg": "abc",
      "VisContact": "0101",
      "VisEmailId": "jd@example.com"
    },
    {
      "VKey": "Johnny johnson 0102 jj@example.com",
      "VisName": "johnny",
      "VisOrg": "xyz",
      "VisContact": "0102",
      "VisEmailId": "jj@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am binding this array with visnames in a autoselect dropdown in reactjs. Now when i type and select *visname* **john**, i need to print other keys like *visorg* and *viscontact*. how can i do that ?

[image]

on selecting john doe, console.log should print

> john doe , abc , 0101

Comment: Please attach your source code for dropdown

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt. Please also use appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get full object after drop down selection you can try this

Handle selected option from dropdown

```
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption }, () =>
      console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption)
      console.log(`Selected Object:`, selectedOption.value)
      // here you will get selected option and object value

    );
  };
```

Map your array for showing drop down lists. **Assuming your array name is dropDownArray.**

```
<Select
  value={selectedOption}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  options={this.props.dropDownArray.map((data, index) => {
    return {
      label: data.VisName,
      value: data,
      key: index
    };
  })}
/>
```